# How to apply a formula one row at a time in R - row 2's values from calculated values of row 1

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a data frame where I need to apply a formula to create new columns. The catch is, I need to calculate these numbers one row at a time. For eg,

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:10),c(21:30),5,10)
names(df) <- c('a','b','c','d')
```

I now need to create columns 'c' and 'd' as follows. Column 'c' whose R1 value is fixed as 5. But from R2 onwards the value of 'c' is calculated as (c (from previous row) - b(from previous row). Column 'd' R1 value is fixed as 10, but from R2 onwards, 'd' is calculated as 'c' from R2 - d from previous row.
I want my output to look like this:

```
A  B   C    D
1  21  5   10
2  22 -16 -26
3  23 -38 -12
```

And so on. My actual data has over 1000 rows and 18 columns. For every row, 5 of the column values come from different columns of the previous row only (no other rows). And the rest of the column values are calculated from these newly calculated row values. I am quite at a loss in creating a formula that will apply my formulae to each row, calculate values for that row and then move to the next row. I know that I have simplified the problem a bit here, but this captures the essence of what I am attempting.

This is what I attempted:

```
df <- within(df, {

v1 <- shift(c)
v2 <- shift(d)
c <- v1-shift(b)
d <- c-v2
})
```

However, I need to apply this only from row 2 onwards and I have no idea how to do that.Because of that, I get something like this:

```
a  b  c  d  v2  v1
1  21 NA NA NA  NA
2  22 4  -6 10  5
3  23 4  -6 10  5
```

I only get these values repeatedly for c, and d (4, -6, 10, 5).

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiA0L.jpg)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30, c = 5:-4, d = 10)

for (i in (2:nrow(df))) {
  df[i, "c"] <- df[i - 1, "c"] - df[i - 1, "b"]
  df[i, "d"] <- df[i, "c"] - df[i - 1, "d"]
}

df[1:3, ]
  a  b   c   d
1 1 21   5  10
2 2 22 -16 -26
3 3 23 -38 -12
```

Edit: adapting to your comment

```
# Let's define the coefficients of the equations into a dataframe
equation1 <- c("c", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0) # c (from previous row) - b(from previous row)
equation2 <- c("d", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1) # d is calculated as 'c' from R2 - d from previous row
equations <- data.frame(rbind(equation1,equation2), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(equations) <- c("y","a","b","c","d","a_previous","b_previous","c_previous","d_previous")
equations
#  y  a b c d a_previous b_previous c_previous d_previous
# "c" 0 0 0 0          0         -1          1          0
# "d" 0 0 1 0          0          0          0         -1

# define function to mutiply the rows of the dataframes 
sumProd <- function(vect1, vect2) {
  return(as.numeric(as.numeric(vect1) %*% as.numeric(vect2)))
}

# Apply the formulas to the originaldataframe
for (i in (2:nrow(df))) {
  for(e in 1:nrow(equations)) {
    df[i, equations[e, 'y']] <- sumProd(equations[e, c('a','b','c','d')], df[i, c('a','b','c','d')]) +
                                  sumProd(equations[e, paste0(c('a','b','c','d'),'_previous')], df[i - 1, c('a','b','c','d')])
  }
}
df[1:3,]
  a  b   c   d
1 1 21   5  10
2 2 22 -16 -26
3 3 23 -38 -12
```

Comment: I should have been clearer about the formula that I want in 'c' I guess. I just used c-1 as an example. In my actual research, it is more like an equation (like c= c(from prev R) + x*(d from prev R), where x is from this row). So, I cannot generate either c or d from a simple sequence in df.

Comment: I think you can adapt this code to what you need. Or be more precise with your example so we can help ;)

Comment: I am using linear equations for each column.

    c(R2) = constant_1 * c(R1) + constant_2 * d(R1)
    d(R2) = constant_3 * c(R2) + constant_3 * d(R1)^2 + constant_4

I have 7 such equations. It's sort of like time-series, where my values from this period come from previous period values.

Comment: So it's smth like this for c(R2) `df[i, "c"] = constant_1 * df[i - 1, "c"] + constant_2 * df[i - 1, "d"]` where i equals 2. And you can go onwards.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried doing initially, the only problem with that is, for each one of my variables, I am going to have to type df[i,"colname"] inside the equation. I have about 13 such columns in total where each column has a formula that has a value from another column in its row or the previous row. It ends up looking something like this, 

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) { 
  
  df[i,"h_t_1"] <- df[(i-1),"ht"]
  df[i,"q_t_1"] <- df[(i-1),"qt"]
  df[i,"y_t_1"] <- df[(i-1),"yt"]

df[i,"nu_h_t_1"] <- ch_p*df[i,"y_t_1"] + ah_p*((df[i,"h_t_1"])^2)/df[i,"y_t_1"] -  ah_p*(eta_p^2)*df[i,"h_t_1"]

Comment: While I don't mind the typing, I was hoping to find out if there was a more elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: You can store the coefficients into a matrix and then apply some products between this matrix and your dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It didn't even occur to me to use matrices!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant way to do it with a for loop but it works. Your column c sounds like a simple sequence to me. 
This is waht I would do:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:10),c(21:30),5,10)
names(df) <- c('a','b','c','d')

# Use a simple sequence for c 
df$c <- seq(5,5-(dim(df)[1]-1))


# Use for loop to calculate d             

for(i in 2:(length(df$d)-1))
{
  df$d[i] <- df$c[i] - df$d[i-1]
}

> df
    a  b  c  d
1   1 21  5 10
2   2 22  4 -6
3   3 23  3  9
4   4 24  2 -7
5   5 25  1  8
6   6 26  0 -8
7   7 27 -1  7
8   8 28 -2 -9
9   9 29 -3  6
10 10 30 -4 10
```

Comment: I should have been clearer about the formula that I want in 'c' I guess. I just used c-1 as an example. In my actual research, it is more like an equation (like c= c(from prev R) + x*(d from prev R), where x is from this row). So, I cannot generate either c or d from a simple sequence in df.